# How to capture a click to close a modal on everything but the modal

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am using a modal similar to the modal component in the Vue docs here: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/modal.html (ok, exactly like it).

I'd like to make it so that clicking anywhere outside the modal closes it. How would I do this?

Comment: you can use vuex to store and manage the modal's state(open or close),you also can use event bus to notification modal open or close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This fixed it by detecting which class was clicked on:

```
  <div class="modal-mask" @click="closeModal($event)">
    <div class="modal-wrapper">
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
```

and later in component:

```
  methods:{
    closeModal(event){
      if(event.target.className == 'modal-wrapper'){
        EventBus.$emit('hideModal');
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to make it so when anything else is clicked the message is hidden. You might need to change it to make it work with your script.

```
//The background of the image, the area that clicking makes it close.
var modalBackground = document.getElementsById("modal-mask")[0];
window.onclick = function(e) {
    //Testing if the target is the background
    if (e.target == modalBackground ) {
        //Hides the message
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```